# (Inequality) If a>b, then should a>=b be considered correct (not vice-versa)?

Tags: inequality

(Inequality)  If we know that a>b, but in exam we dont find any such option, then should selecting the option a>=b be considered as a correct answer (not vice-versa)? Please provide any mathematical or logical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If a>b then a>=b is always true because >= means either greater(which is true) or equal to.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1264375)

Comment: ok, I will follow this from next time.